# Missing method ReadAsAsync in assembly ..., type System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, raspbian

I created an application (DroneClient) that is communicating with a Web Api 2 server through requests (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE). The application itself runs fine in Visual Studio because I installed the *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client* package (NuGet package). However, I need this application to run from a terminal in Debian (Raspbian more exactly).

I created the executable for my DroneClient app and I run it with **mono**.
The Form of the application appears on the screen but the moment I press the button that should display some data (strings) from the local database, I get the error *Missing method ReadAsAsync in assembly ..., type System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions*. (Indeed, I use this method and it works in VS).

No matter how I try to search for a solution, everything I find are solutions for when people did not install the *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client* (which is not the case for me, everything works inside Visual Studio).

Is there something I can add/install so that the ReadAsAsync methods can be executed from Raspbian terminal?

Thank you.

Comment: What files are you copying over to the other client? If you are just copying the generated .exe file over, then you could well be missing other libraries, but some will be available already within windows. Copy everything from the /bin folder, including all the DLLs, as well as the .exe and try that.

Comment: I found in the end that I sould compile the project with mono in Windows and then just send the executable in linux. Mono should be able to support all the libraries that I use while compiling.